# Laravel/homestead - No input file specified

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I'm new to Laravel, trying to set up very first website, but getting "No input file specified" when trying to open my website "belekas.test"
I believe that my yaml and hosts files are correct, but will include pictures of it.

Things I have tried:

`vagrant halt`

`vagrant up`

`vagrant ssh`

`vagrant reload --provision`

`serve homestead.app public`

`sudo service nginx restart`

yaml:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox


folders:
    - map: ~/Laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Laravel

sites:
    - map: belekas.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Laravel/belekas/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

hosts: `192.168.10.10 belekas.test`

that's how my terminal looks like:

[image]

Update: After running `vagrant up --provision` and `vagrant reload --provision` few times, my page load into another Class `'Illuminate\Session\Store' not found` error

[image]

Comment: Have you exited SSH and run `vagrant reload --provision` after creating your project?

Comment: I believe I did, also did it manually vagrant halt and vagrant up vagrant ssh

Comment: Can you show your nginx file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`? There should be one specifically for belekas.test

Comment: could you please specify where should I check? if we are talking about `windows/system32/drivers/etc/` ? I got 6 files in this folder: hosts, hosts.ics, lmhosts.sam, networks, protocol, services

Comment: Sorry, that file is within your Vagrant environment. Once you're logged in, you should be able to find that file.

Comment: @aynber sorry I tried but couldn't locate this directory, maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

All fixed and running.
This was caused by having extra unwanted routes while managing the folders
it was username/homestead/homestead instead of username/homestead.
Also it could have potentially have caused issues that my hosts file was not edited properly, the name of my website was not aligned with example name.